# How to get particular value from database table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my database table i have one column having this data

```
background: linear-gradient(top , rgb(255,104,0) 0% , rgb(255,68,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top , rgb(255,104,0) 0% , rgb(255,68,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top , rgb(255,104,0) 0% , rgb(255,68,0) 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top , rgb(255,104,0) 0% , rgb(255,68,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , rgb(255,104,0) 0% , rgb(255,68,0) 100%);
```

From this i want only rgb values like

```
rgb(255, 104, 0) 0%  and rgb(255,68,0) 100%
```

I write code in normal PHP like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt_site_settings
WHERE NOT (
Button_Gradient_Background_Color LIKE  '%rgb%')
```

but it does not work properly and i want in codeignter model.

How can i do it?

Comment: why you adding the 'a' in filter string in  like operator

Comment: one more thing your current query will return all the content from specific row

Comment: See my answer. It's working or not? @naresh

Answer (score 0):

**Check This** it is in core PHP.

```
<?php 
   $color= "rgb(255,104,0)";
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dt_site_settings` WHERE Button_Gradient_Background_Color like '%$color%'");
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $find = $data['Button_Gradient_Background_Color'];
   $ex =  explode(',',$find);
   $first_color = $ex[1].','.$ex[2].','.$ex[3];
   $second_color = $ex[4].','.$ex[5].','.$ex[6];
   echo '<br>'.$first_color .'<br>';
   echo '<br>'.$second_color .'<br>';
?>
```